# Burninate [burning]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

All the six questions tagged with [burning](/questions/tagged/burning) are related with CD burning and DVD burning.

We already have [cd-burning](/questions/tagged/cd-burning) and [dvd-burning](/questions/tagged/dvd-burning) tags.

So, what should we do?

Comment: How about [cd-burninating] and [dvd-burninating]?

Comment: Hrm, only 6 questions? Doesn't really seem like something that needs to be discussed on Meta. One person with 6 minutes to spare could handle that retagging, like Zaheer and myself just did. It's pretty obvious in the case of all those questions that the [burning] tag refers to either CD or DVD burning.

Comment: Perhaps the real question here should have been if we really need separate [tag:cd-burning] and [tag:dvd-burning] tags, or if a generic [tag:disc-burning] tag would not be sufficient.

Comment: Since this burninate request has been satisfied, can a mod tag this with [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @mc10, yes a mod should tag with status-completed.

Comment: @CodyGray when would that even be needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: All hail Trogdor!]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything *so* different between CD burning and DVD burning that they should have separate tags.

On the other hand, why is the tag [burning](/questions/tagged/burning) or [cd-burning](/questions/tagged/cd-burning)? Shouldn't the tags be the names of programming languages/libraries? I don't think that a tag saying what can I do is a good tag in first place.

Comment: Not *all* tags need to be programming languages or libraries. Burning a disc is a common action, and basically the same regardless of the particular language that you're using.

Comment: But the CD burning itself has nothing to do with programming, it is computer usage. Only when some library is involved, it becomes programming question.

Comment: see the questions tagged with cd-burning, that they have related to programming.